# Using Spring Mvc WebApplicationInitializer, ApplicationContextInitializer and ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I use java-based Spring Mvc configuration.

I register the Spring dispatcher servlet in the WebApplicationInitializer implementation.
Load Spring ApplicationContext configuration files. Logic of Spring profiles management is implemented in the ApplicationContextInitializer implementation. And it worked fine.

Here are full examples of the original files:
**WebApplicationInitializer**

```
public class SpringMvcExampleWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
        registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerDispatcherServlet(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = createContext(WebMvcContextConfiguration.class, InfrastructureContextConfiguration.class);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setContextInitializers(new SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer());
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(annotatedClasses);
        return context;
    }

    private void registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class);
        registration.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD),
                false, DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME);
    }
}
```

**SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer**

```
public class SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = ctx.getEnvironment();
        List<String> profiles = new ArrayList<String>(getProfiles());
        if( profiles == null || profiles.isEmpty() )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Profiles have not been configured");
        }
        environment.setActiveProfiles(profiles.toArray( new String[0]));
    }

    //TODO add logic
    private Collection<String> getProfiles() {
        return Lists.newArrayList("file_based", "test_data");
    }
}
```

**InfrastructureContextConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.savdev.springmvcexample.repository", "com.savdev.springmvcexample.config"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.savdev.springmvcexample.repository"})
public class InfrastructureContextConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Profile(value = "file_based")
    @PropertySource("classpath:/db/config/file_based.properties")
    public static class FileBasedConfiguration {

        @Inject
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");
        liquibase.setDropFirst(true);
        return liquibase;
    }
```

Then I added Spring Security context configuration to the application. To use it the `DelegatingFilterProxy` have to be loaded. I\ve updated the configuration:

Added new method and invoked it in the `onStartup`:

```
private void registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter(
            BeanIds.SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN,
            new DelegatingFilterProxy());
    springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}

@Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    ...
    registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
    ...
    registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
}
```

Now when I try to request any url I'm getting the error:

```
message No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:251)
```

Ok, I added the following:

```
        private static final Class<?>[] configurationClasses = new Class<?>[]{
                WebMvcContextConfiguration.class, InfrastructureContextConfiguration.class};
    ...

private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
    WebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(configurationClasses);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
}
```

And invoked it from:

```
@Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    registerListener(servletContext);
    registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
    registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(servletContext);
    registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
}
```

The error has gone.

But all beans that depend on Spring profile are not loaded now. Adding the `ContextLoaderListener` has broken the  `SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer` logic.

```
No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency
```

What can I do to resolve it? Any ideas, please?

Here is the full updated web initializer class:

```
public class SpringMvcExampleWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    private static final Class<?>[] configurationClasses = new Class<?>[]{
            WebMvcContextConfiguration.class, InfrastructureContextConfiguration.class};


    @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerListener(servletContext);
        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
        registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(servletContext);
        registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter(
                BeanIds.SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN,
                new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

    private void registerDispatcherServlet(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = createContext(WebMvcContextConfiguration.class, InfrastructureContextConfiguration.class);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setContextInitializers(new SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer());
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(annotatedClasses);
//        context.refresh();
        return context;
    }

    private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(configurationClasses);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
//        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    }

    private void registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class);
        registration.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD),
                false, DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your full `SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer` and specify which `@Configuration` class contains profiles and which `@Configuration` class has the `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Comment: Your problem is the fact that you are loading everything twice and that you are only specifing the initializer on the `DispatcherServlet`  and not on the `ContextLoaderListener`. You should split your configuration where the `ContextLoaderListener` loads the general things (services, daos, infrastructure etc.) and the `DispatcherServlet` only the web related things (controllers, viewresovlers etc).

Comment: @M.Deinum, I tried to load web configuraion only in dispatcher servlet, and the InfrastructureContextConfiguration only via ContextLoaderListener. But the problem is that profiles are used by InfrastructureContextConfiguration. And they are activated only via SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer for web dispatcher servlet. And as a result, I got the same error:( The DataSource bean is not loaded.

Comment: As mentioned you are only specifying the `SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer` not on the `ContextLoaderListener`. You specify it for the `ContextLoaderListener` through a context-param (which you can set directly on the `ServletContext`).

Comment: @M.Deinum, it helped! Thank you very much!! But could you tell me which option is the best one. Profiles my by used by different configuration files (services, daos, infrastructure, web) and I'd like to specify the only ApplicationContextInitializer. Now I invoke it in a couple of methods: When register and configure DispatcherServlet, second when register ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: @M.Deinum, and is there a way to pass ApplicationContextInitializer as class, not as string. Now it is configured as:     private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {  servletContext.setInitParameter("contextInitializerClasses","com.savdev.springmvcexample.web.config.SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer" ); WebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(configurationClasses); servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));...

Comment: No, currently there isn't at least not for the `ContextLoaderListener`. If you want this chained I suggest you register [an enhancement request](http://jira.springsource.org)

Answer (score 0):

As M.Deinum recommended I set the profiles initialier to the `ServletContext`, instead of setting it to `DispatcherServlet`. Here is the updated configuration:

```
@Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    configureServletContext( servletContext );
    registerListener(servletContext);
    registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
    ...
}

private void configureServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    String initializerClasses = servletContext.getInitParameter(ContextLoader.CONTEXT_INITIALIZER_CLASSES_PARAM);
    String profilesInitClassName = SpringMvcExampleProfilesInitializer.class.getName();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(initializerClasses)) {
        initializerClasses += " " + profilesInitClassName;
    }
    else {
        initializerClasses = profilesInitClassName;
    }
    servletContext.setInitParameter(ContextLoader.CONTEXT_INITIALIZER_CLASSES_PARAM, initializerClasses);
}
```

Comment: Actually you need both. The one in the `ServletContext` are used by the `ContextLoaderListener` whereas the other ones are used by the `DispatcherSevlet`.